# Объясните строку кода с методом HashMap, Java

Tags: java, for, java-hashmap

Я новичок в Java, объясните пожалуйста как пошагово работает этот метод :
`{map.put(str, map.get(str) + 1);`
Как я понял он сначала перезаписывает ключ в колекцию, потом возращает ключ и прибавляет к  вэлью 12

```
 Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String str : list) {
        if  (map.containsKey(str)) 
            {map.put(str, map.get(str) + 1);
        } else {
            map.put(str, 1);
        }
```

Comment: Попробуй продебажить, вот [ссылка](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/2463-debug-v-intellij-idea-gayd-dlja-novichkov) как дебажить

Comment: `{map.put(str, map.get(str) + 1);` дословно означает `извлечь значение по ключу str, увеличить значение на 1, записать обрвтно по тому же ключу.`

Comment: Понял спасибо !

Comment: *В данный момент* код в вопросе подсчитывает количествa повторений одинаковых строк в списке `list`.